# Slice multiple dataframes based in different ranges values in a specific column and categorize them in new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to select values within 5 certain ranges for a given column, and to each different dataframe, apply in a new column, a label?

I mean, I have a list a of dataframes. All dataframes have 2 columns and share the same first column, but differs in the second (header and values). For example:

```
>> df1
   GeneID   A
     1     0.3 
     2     0.0
     3     143
     4      9
     5     0.6

>> df2
   GeneID   B
     1     0.2 
     2     0.3
     3     0.1
     4     0.7
     5     0.4

  ....
```

I would like to:

1. For each dataframe on the list, perform a calculation which gives the probability of that value occur within 1 of 5 different range. Append a new column with those values;
2. For each dataframe on the list, attach the respective range label in another new column.

Where the ranges are:

```
*Range_Values* -> *Range_Label*

   **[0]**     ->   'l1'

  **]0,1]**    ->   'l2'

 **]1,10]**    ->   'l3'

**]10,100]**   ->   'l4'

  **>100**        'l5'
```

This 2 steps approaches would led to something like:

```
>> list_dfs[df1]
   GeneID    A    Prob_val     Exp_prof
      1     0.3     0.4         'l2'
      2     0.0     0.2         'l1'
      3     143     0.2         'l5'
      4      9      0.2         'l3'
      5     0.6     0.4         'l2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first define the bins and labels -

```
bins = [0, 1, 10, 100, float("inf")]
labels = ['l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l4', 'l5']
```

Then use [`pd.cut()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) -

```
pd.cut(df1['A'], bins, right=False)
```

There is a `labels` parameter in `pd.cut()` that you can use to get labels -

```
pd.cut(df1['A'], bins, labels=labels, right=False)
```

You can use the `bins` generated to compute probabilities I leave it upto you to do that.

You can do this for the rest of the `dfs` in a loop and finally assign them to a list -

```
list_dfs = [df1, df2, ...]
```

If you have dynamic number of `dfs` use a loop -

**Framework**

```
for df in dfs:
    df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins, right=False)
    df['label'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins, labels=labels, right=False)
```

Comment: Although it is a good answer, someting must be wrong with the labels. The labels are not working fine, it does not match the proper range.

Comment: @JoãoFernandes you were right. I have updated the ans to include `l6`. The reason being I decided to include the `float("inf")` to capture values greater than `100`

Comment: Following your codethe label `l1` will be given to the bin `[0,1]` since the singleton `[0]` won't be taken in to account. You could consider adding a new category for this in order to match the desired mapping.

Answer (score 1):

For the labels and bins, you can use `pandas.cut`. Note that you can't use a singleton as a bin in this function. Therefore you will have to create it afterwards. Here is how you can do this.

First I recreate one of your dataframes:

```
    import io
temp = u"""
GeneID    A
      1     0.3
      2     0.0
      3     143
      4      9
      5     0.6"""
foo = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),delim_whitespace = True)
```

Then I create the new column and fill the `NaN` values with the label `l1` which corresponds to the singleton `[0]`.

```
foo['Exp_prof'] = pd.cut(foo.A,bins = [0,1,10,100,np.inf],labels = ['l2','l3','l4','l5'])
foo['Exp_prof'] = foo['Exp_prof'].cat.add_categories(['l1'])
foo['Exp_prof'] = foo['Exp_prof'].fillna('l1')
```

And I use this new column to compute the probabilities:

```
foo['Prob_val'] = foo.Exp_prof.map((foo.Exp_prof.value_counts()/len(foo)).to_dict())
```

And the output is:

```
    GeneID  A       Exp_prof    Prob_val
0   1       0.3     l2          0.4
1   2       0.0     l1          0.2
2   3       143.0   l5          0.2
3   4       9.0     l3          0.2
4   5       0.6     l2          0.4
```

Comment: Thar works just fine, thank you ! 
The probability calculi is based on the **A** column range or in the frequency of labels just added as well. See, in this case, the label l2 as a prob value of **0.4** since it is 2/5

Comment: I edited my answer to add the computation of these probabilities.